# Haskell deduced too strict type

Tags: haskell, type-inference

*Disclaimer: I’m just starting to learn Haskell and I’m not sure “strict” is the right word here.*

I was trying to narrow down my problem but I couldn’t really find the issue, so here is my code that **doesn’t compile**:

```
module Json where
import Data.List (intersperse)

data JNode = 
    JObject [(String, JNode)]
  | JArray  [JNode]
  | JString String
  | JNumber Double
  | JBool   Bool
  | JNull

instance Show JNode where
  show = show_node 0 where
    glue = foldl (++) ""
    show_tabs n              = glue $ take n $ repeat "  "
    show_list n              = glue . intersperse ",\n" . map (show_pair (n + 1))
    show_sect n l r xs       = glue ["\n", tabs, l, "\n", show_list n xs, "\n", tabs, r] where tabs = show_tabs n
    -- show_pair :: (Show a) => Int -> (a, JNode) -> String -- works when uncommented
    show_pair n (name,  val) = glue [show_tabs n, show name, " : ", show_node n val]
    show_node n (JObject xs) = show_sect n "{" "}" xs
    show_node n (JArray  xs) = show_sect n "[" "]" $ zip [0..] xs
    show_node n (JString x ) = show x
    show_node n (JNumber x ) = show x
    show_node n (JBool   x ) = show x
    show_node n (JNull     ) = "null"
```

The error is:

```
Prelude> :l scripts\json.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Json             ( scripts\json.hs, interpreted )

scripts\json.hs:21:59:
    No instance for (Enum String)
      arising from the arithmetic sequence `0 .. '
    In the first argument of `zip', namely `([0 .. ])'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `zip ([0 .. ]) xs'
    In the expression: show_sect n "[" "]" $ zip ([0 .. ]) xs

scripts\json.hs:21:60:
    No instance for (Num String) arising from the literal `0'
    In the expression: 0
    In the first argument of `zip', namely `[0 .. ]'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `zip [0 .. ] xs'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

**Take a look at the line of code with the comment.** Apparently, when there is no type declaration, it requires me to pass `String` instead of just `Show a`. Funny enough, it still requires `name` to be a `String` when I don’t even use it, e.g. when replacing `show_pair` implementation with this:

```
show_pair n (name,  val) = show_node n val
```

Can someone explain to me why it works the way it does?

---

**Simplified version** of my code with the same issue in case anyone was going to improve the answer:

```
data TFoo = 
    FooStr (String, TFoo)
  | FooNum (Int,    TFoo)

-- show_pair :: (a, TFoo) -> String
show_pair (_,    val) = show_node val
show_node (FooStr  x) = show_pair x
show_node (FooNum  x) = show_pair x
```

Comment: `snake_case` is not usually used in Haskell, `camelCase` is the most adhered to naming style.

Comment: I highly recommend breaking all those local functions out to the top level and giving each a type signature. You don't need to export them from your module, but the whole mess will be a lot easier to read and work with.

Comment: More generally, when you have a type error and don't know where the problem is, adding some type signatures will often help you get more useful error messages. The `ScopedTypeVariables` extension is necessary in some cases to give a type signature to a local binding. I don't think that's the case here, but I suspect your function would be better broken in pieces anyway.

Comment: One thing I learned when writing Haskell (and this mirrors the above comment): When in doubt, add signatures! Tell it exactly what you want to limit its guessing. It may be pretty good guessing types most of the time, but giving it help will always benefit you!

Comment: By the way, `foldl (++) ""` is a really inefficient way to concatenate strings. The fast way is `foldr (++) ""`, or, generalizing to lists, `foldr (++) []`, better known as `concat`.

Answer (score 9):

**tl;dr**: always use explicit signatures when you want something to be polymorphic.

---

In [System F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F) (which is what Haskell's type system is based on) every type variable that's used for polymorphism needs to be explicitly quantified into scope by a type-level-lambda / for-all (∀). So in fact you'd need to have

```
show_pair :: ∀ a. (Show a) => Int -> (a, JNode) -> String
```

It could be argued that Haskell should require this too, but it doesn't. It just quantifies any variable that you mention in an explicit signature<sup>†</sup>, so you can simply write

```
show_pair :: (Show a) => Int -> (a, JNode) -> String
```

Also, it tries to introduce as many type variables as possible into *top-level bindings* without signature<sup>‡</sup>.

<del>However, it does not automatically introduce any type variables into *local* bindings. Since the compiler knows exactly where `show_pair` is used, it has a full context of at least one type instantiation that you will need to have. What it assumes is that you *only* need one instantiation. With that it tries to infer some type for a *monomorphic* `show_pair`, and fails. Only by adding an explicit signature do you force the compiler to consider a polymorphic signature.</del> <sup>As remarked in the comments, this isn't actually true because already since GHC-7.0, there's a thing called [let generalisation](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/blog/LetGeneralisationInGhc7) which does make local bindings polymorphic even without signature. I wasn't aware that this is on by default. — Even if it's *possible* to omit the signatures, polymorphic functions should still better have them IMO.</sup>

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Provided you've not already introduced that variable in a higher scope, with the `-XScopedTypeVariables` extension.</sub>

<sup>‡</sup><sub>Unfortunately, the [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/MonomorphismRestriction) makes this awfully hard to rely on.</sub>

Comment: Why doesn't let generalization catch this?

Comment: @dfeuer I guess it's because of mutual recursion. Generalization happens for the whole group of mutually recursive definitions, but then it's too late.

Comment: @chi, I guess that's what the `RelaxedPolyRec` or whatever it's called is about? Or is that also top level only? It seems the standard is a bit too fussy here. In any case, I'm in the obsessive type signature writing camp, and terrified of libraries that make that painful.

Comment: Pretty sure it's because of polymorphic recursion, and it would be worse without `RelaxedPolyRec`: then *all* the functions would need signatures. The local bindings thing is `MonoLocalBinds`, and if you enable that this code won't work even with the signature on `show_pair`.

Comment: The last paragraph of this answer is misleading or wrong: as already alluded to by other comments, let generalization is on by default in the absence of certain other language extensions and its exact purpose is to make local bindings polymorphic.

Comment: @ReidBarton: right you are, and it means my answer isn't really correct. Hopefully someone'd write a proper one...

Comment: Let generalization is already in Hindley Milner, and was included in Haskell from the get go. The tricky bit here is really the polymorphic recursion, which H-M prohibits outright.

Answer (score 0):

Well I suppose you expect `[0..]` to be considered a `[Int]` while it seems not to be the case. And that would be probably because `show_node` for `JObject` passes `[(String, JNode)]` as the same parameter as `JArray` passes `[(SOMETHING_UNKNOWN, JNode)]` into `show_sect`.

Try forcing the type just on the expression `[0..]` that you zip together with the array elements: `zip ([0..] :: [Int]) xs`. I am confident that the problem is the inferred type of `show_sect`.

I would highly recommend to provide some type annotations, I think it is a good practice to do so. I am not too familiar with type inference in Haskell though.